# R : rename columns time series data

Tags: r, rename

I am trying to rename the columns of a time series using assign function as follows -

```
assign(colnames(paste0(<logic_to_get_dataset>)),
c(<logic_to_get_column_names>))
```

I am getting a warning : `In assign(colnames(get(paste0("xvars_", TopVars[j, 1], "_lag",  :
  only the first element is used as variable name`

also, the column name assignment does not happen. I think this is happening because of colnames() function. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I've never used `assign()`... Is it necessary in this situation?

Comment: I m using a for loop to perform a set of operations on 25 datasets and this is one of the operations. I am ware of only assign() that works in such cases. I am open to trying out other ways as well.

Comment: Does the for loop in the assign example help (cran help page)? It loops to do the paste and also assigns afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that assign only looks at the first element of the vector.

You can try this, for example:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 4:2)
within(df, assign(colnames(df),c('a','b'))
```

You'll notice that R only looks at the first variable, and it tries to reassign the values that are described by those column names to the second value.  This behavior is obviously not what you're looking for.

Unfortunately, it's kind of hackey, but you can always use something like this

```
data.frame.name = get_df()#some function that returns text
data.frame.columns = get_cols()#some function that returns text
eval(parse(text = paste0('colnames(',data.frame.name,') = c(',
 paste(data.frame.columns,collapse = ','),')')))
```

I prefer to avoid doing these kinds of expressions, but it should work as intended.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first solution but it errors out. `Error in UseMethod("within") : 
  no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "c('mts', 'ts', 'matrix')"`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The first part wasn't supposed to be a solution.  It basically showed that `assign()` isn't a useful tool in this case.  I would create the expression itself and then parse and evaluate it (with `eval()` and `parse()`).  There might be another way to use `assign()` to do this, but I am unaware.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes -

```
    temp_var <- paste0('colnames(var_',TopLines[j,1],'_lag',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,],'_',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,]+12 , 
       ') <-  c(gsub( "xt',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,],'" , "xt',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,],'__',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,]+12, 
       '", colnames(var_',TopLines[j,1],'_xt',get(paste0('uniqLg_',TopLines[j,1]))[k,],')))')

print(temp_var )

eval(parse( text=temp_var ))
```

where TopLines is a data frame with one column and contains a list of lines.                                                         The only problem with this method is, I can't test the output of eval unless I actually open the dataset and see if the changes have been affected.